# Animate the change between detailviews on UISplitViewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uisplitviewcontroller

Currently This is how i change between detailviews from the right navigation bar

```
UIViewController <SubstitutableDetailViewController> *detailViewController = nil;

NSString * type = [self selectview:arb];

DetailViewController *newDetailViewController = [[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:type bundle:nil];
detailViewController = newDetailViewController;
NSArray *viewControllers = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:self.navigationController, detailViewController, nil];
splitViewController.viewControllers = viewControllers;

[viewControllers release];
[detailViewController release];
```

There are lots of different nibs which it can change to

What i want to do is change between these with an effect sliding like the navigation controller would be good

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? If so, would be great if you could post your solution as an answer. I'm trying to figure out the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

You could place all 'linked' detail views in one navigation view controller of their own that would nicely deal with the transition between one another. Here is an example: http://www.cimgf.com/2010/05/24/fixing-the-uisplitviewcontroller-template/

Answer (score -1):

I just wonder : is this code working ? you're just changing UIViewControllers, but not the views hierarchy...

Comment: The code works fine, you just need to update the detail view, and not actually push a new (master) view. And you are changing the views to be displayed, you are changing the second view to your new detail view.